# Matrix multiplication and addition using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables

```
Table1:

table_id_one table_id_two
1             2
3             4


Table2

id_one   id_two
5        6
7        7
```

I want matrix multiplication and addition of table1 and table2 using mysql. The result should be

```
Multiply

X  Y
19 22
43 50

Add
X  Y
6  8
10 11
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Do your tables have `id` columns that you can use to relate the rows in the two tables?

Comment: If you want to treat the table as a matrix, you need to know the order of the rows. MySQL tables don't have any ordering, you need a column to indicate the order.

Comment: How did you solve it? @ArjunJain